# How should I optimize my code? - Delete duplicate-value nodes from a sorted linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to solve this problem - [Remove duplicate-values from sorted linked list](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/delete-duplicate-value-nodes-from-a-sorted-linked-list/problem?isFullScreen=true)

I am getting run-time error for some test cases while it is working for some other test cases. It would mean a lot If anyone can suggest some methods on how should I optimize the code?

```
#
# For your reference:
#
# SinglyLinkedListNode:
#     int data
#     SinglyLinkedListNode next
#
#

def removeDuplicates(head):
    if head is None:
        return None
    else:

        current = head
        prev = SinglyLinkedListNode("")
        prev.next = head

        while current.next != None and current != None: 

            if prev.data != current.data:
                prev = prev.next
                current = current.next
            else:

                current = current.next
                while(current != None and prev.data == current.data and current.next != None):
                    current = current.next
                if (current.next == None):
                    prev.next = None

                prev.next = current
                prev = prev.next
                if current != None and current.next != None: 
                    current = current.next

        if current.next == None and current != None: 
            if prev.data != current.data:
                prev = prev.next
            else:
                prev.next = None

        return head
```

> > > UPDATE: I just changed my approach and used a list to track the previous occurred values for comparing. [The correct code is here now](https://github.com/dear-s/Hackerrank-solutions---Python/blob/master/Delete%20duplicate-value%20nodes%20from%20a%20sorted%20linked%20list). Thanks, everyone!! Although I would love to know if there are any ways to correct the above-given code.

Comment: Optimization and correctness/errors are two different things. I wouldn't worry about optimization until you've resolved the error. What error are you getting? Have you looked at the test cases you're failing on?

Comment: @ggorlen it's just showing "Runtime error" in the compiler message box!! You can see this test case for example - https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1157/input05.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1577612248&Signature=xdt1ienDIm3k0uCy0OdUAqY3Xnc%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: Check this case: `1,1,1`. I hope you'll be able to figure out the error in your approach. If not, let me know here.

Comment: @AjayDabas I am still receiving runtime error! It's working for the given base test cases but I don't seem to understand where is the problem. I have however updated the code after considering all the changes that are mentioned below!

Comment: @Sanya: It's better not to update the code after there are answers on the post. As long as the edits are trivial it should be fine. Avoid having edits that invalidate the answers.

Comment: The list approach you've mentioned as a part of update takes O(n) extra space and has O(n^2) time complexity. The approach in the original post is the optimal one.

Comment: Also in `while current.next != None and current != None:` the second condition should be the first one in the order.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni okay. Sorry I didn't know about that. And thanks for the link as well. I will note that point from now on.

Answer (score 1):

I think this part will mess you up:

```
while(prev.data == current.data):
    current = current.next
prev.next = current
prev = prev.next
current = current.next
```

If the loop is triggered, right after you are assuming that the link has a next item, which it might not, I would probably put a check here to prevent that potential case from happening.

Possibly something like this:

```
while (current != None && prev.data == current.data):
    current = current.next;
prev.next = current;
prev = prev.next;
```

Actually, do we really need the "current = current.next" line after?  And that if logic that follows, aren't we already doing the None check in the big while loop, and wouldn't prev already be None at the end of the loop we fixed here?

Comment: I fixed the code and tried running but no improvement. I am still getting a Runtime error. And about the last line "current = current.next", in order to run the while loop and going forward, shouldn't we have to mention it in else block as well - explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get runtime error because you miss to check if `current` is `None` at multiple places.

```
def removeDuplicates(head):
    if head is None:
        return None
    else:

        current = head
        prev = SinglyLinkedListNode("")
        prev.next = head

        while current != None and current.next != None: #check if current is None

            if prev.data != current.data:
                prev = prev.next
                current = current.next
            else:

                current = current.next
                while(current != None and prev.data == current.data): #check if current is None
                    current = current.next
                prev.next = current
                prev = prev.next
                if current != None: #check if current is None
                    current = current.next

        if current != None and current.next == None: #check if current is None
            if prev.data != current.data:
                prev = prev.next
            else:
                prev.next = None

    return head
```

In the above code, my intention is not to clean up or make the code better for you. But to bring to your notice wherever checks are missing.

Also, the algorithmic time complexity of the algorithm you've used here is `O(n)`  (where `n` is total number of nodes in the list) which is the best possible solution to this problem. So no further optimization in algorithmic time complexity is possible. Though the execution time of the code might be improved if you are interested in that but doesn't look like that from the question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reminding me of the necessary conditions which I have to check as well. But it's still not running and I am still getting Runtime Error. However, the two given test-cases are still running. I know improvement should be the last thing to do but I can't seem to find the reason behind Runtime Error even after this adjustment.

Comment: Hey, I understand you are trying to solve the bug. I could help you with a few bugs. If you need help beyond that, then maybe you should start learning how to debug small programs. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. I do think the main question was to understand further scope for optimization, which has been answered.